# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library is giving Null Reference Exception when I am refrencing Missing Value in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, office-interop

```
Application msWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc;
object objMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object endofdoc = "\\endofdoc";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        // add blank documnet in word application

        doc = msWord.Documents.Add(ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss);
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1;

        // add paragraph with document

        para1 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref objMiss);
   }
```

}

When I am assigning to para1, it is giving error -
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

On my local machine it is working fine. But on Remote it is giving errors. 
Note- MS Office is installed on server.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal only with opel XML file format documents. If you need to work with binary files, look for any third-party components that support the server-side execution.

Comment: Thanks Astafiev. If you can provide me some good links on How to use open xml in asp.net then it will be a real help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Interop (Office COM) you should use OpenXML in your scenario. But mastering OpenXML is quite of a task and most people quickly realize that it pays off to just buy some toolkit which uses it and become productive immediately.

One tool that might fit your needs very well is [Docentric Toolkit](http://www.docentric.com/). It is OpenXML toolkit under the hood (it is licensed 3rd party product). You can create Document Object Model programatically from the scratch. From this point of view it gives you similar results as if using Office COM. You can choose .docx or .pdf output.

It is also very convenient for template-based reporting with output in .docx and .pdf. Our company uses it for several years and we have been developing most of our reports using this toolkit. Report template is designed in Word using special add-in. It is so simple that even some end users are designing reports already. Templates contain visual layout, formatting and placeholders for data.

Once the template is ready, it can be called from any .NET application, where data is prepared in the form of .NET objects (e.g. from database or XML). Final documents are then generated with two lines of code, where templates and data are merged together. Final document is pure .docx document.

Answer (score 0):

Start > Run
"mmc -32"  and then add the Component Services snap-in manually
Navigate to Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
Find Microsoft Word 97 – 2003 Document and right click > Properties

Open Identity Tab

Active "The interactive user" instead of the launching user